# Spark Shell - Clear imports

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I 'm facing below problem with Spark Shell. So, in a shell session -

1. I imported following - `import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`
2. Then I realized my mistake and imported correct class - `import java.util.HashMap`

But, now I get following error on running my code -

```
<console>:34: error: reference to HashMap is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import java.util.HashMap
and import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
       val colMap = new HashMap[String, HashMap[String, String]]()
```

Please assist me if I have long running Spark Shell session i.e I do not want to close and reopen my shell. So, is there a way I can clear previous imports and use correct class?

I know that we can also specify full qualified name like - `val colMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, java.util.HashMap[String, String]]()`

But, 'm looking if there is a way to clear an incorrect loaded class?

Thanks

Comment: That's surprising, because I thought spark shell picks imports from history the same way REPL does. What version? `:imports` gives a list of what it sees. Previous HashMap should be shadowed always. You can also try renaming `import java.util.{HashMap => JMap}`. There's no public api to reset selectively.

Comment: I 'm using Spark 2.2 with Scala 2.11.8 , and JRE 1.8

Comment: Also, `:imports` does not shows HashMap.